# Vertex normals incorrect, but face normals look correct?

Tags: normals

I recently imported an FBX from a Max export and about 90% of the model looks fine but for some parts, the vertex normals are 'twisted' even though the face normals look correct. As far as I can tell the parts *are* all manifold and the bad mesh in the image below is just a simple cylinder so I don't think its possible for that to be non-manifold, right? Also when I tried to select non-manifold, nothing selected.

I added a new cylinder for reference and those verts look fine. How can i 'reset' the weird verts without remodelling these parts?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* button in the *Properties Window > Object Data Tab > Geometry Data Panel*? (It is only visible if there is any custom normal data stored)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - AHA! Yep that was totally it! I have never needed to use that button before so i had no clue it was there. If you want to add this as an answer i'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Will do, posted as answer

Comment: You should post that information as an additional answer bellow instead, it's more coherent and could be helpful to someone else searching for answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are probably custom normal data imported from 3Ds MAX

Try the *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* button in the *Properties Window > Object Data Tab > Geometry Data Panel* (It will only be visible if there is any actual custom normal data stored)

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot! I have had this issue before and always just remodeled those parts. You have saved me a ton of time =-D

Comment: So your answer did put me on the right path, but I had to do one more step. After clearing those split normals, Some were still split but not nearly as bad so I added new custom split normals and it seemed to fix the issue. Does that sound right to you?  I updated my post to include the images but figured I'd add a comment to this for clarity.

Comment: I'm really not very familiar with the custom normals workflow, I don't personally use it very often so not sure it is actually right or not. Anyway you should consider posting it as another answer bellow for the sake consistency and clarity instead, as it might also be helpful information for other users with similar problems

Comment: Thats fine, now that i know what to look for I can do some more digging. And I followed your advice and posted another answer. Still keeping yours as chosen answer because it led me in the right direction

Comment: Don't worry about it, if you feel my answer is incomplete you can mark yours as correct instead, no hard feelings

Answer (score 2):

So I am still sticking with the answer chosen, but I had to do one more step to completely fix the issue (I think). When I cleared custom split normals data, most normals were fixed but some were still split (not as bad though):

[image]

So I decided to try adding custom split normals data and when I did, it cleared up those other split normals.

[image]