# (Cycles) What causes textures to act like this?

Tags: modeling

The model in question is converted from MMD using an addon called MMD Tools. The textures load fine with the base engine, but on Cycles it renders with these odd missing chunks. It seems to happen even if I change the lighting type.

I can't provide the .blend file, but know that sometimes the materials work fine, but it occasionally does this. As you can see, the main outfit, facials, and hair textures seem to be fine. But the arms are weird.

[image]

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with your UV's

Comment: if the model itself is identical and unchanged, since of course you created different materials for cycles, there could be the problem, please detail and/or show your complete settings for that material. If you can't share the whole model, simplify it, leave maybe just an arm's portion. If it shows the same issue, the whole model isn't needed.

Comment: It's actually kind of a neat effect - it your going for the tron, scifi, digital look.

Comment: Looks like an issue with either inverted/inconsistent normals, or your mesh has custom split normals saved. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57006/problem-when-importing-obj-to-blender or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57772/vertex-normals-incorrect-but-face-normals-look-correct and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52492/auto-smooth-shading-of-old-file

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. show images of the model in solid shading (no textures), also show an image of some of the material nodes.